# Javascript global array with jquery .push returns empty array in alternate function

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I declare a variable, outside of a function like so:

```
var vitalsValuesChecked = [];
```

then inside of a function I do:

```
vitalsValuesChecked.push('foobar');
```

In a later function I need to loop through the array for the items pushed, and constantly am not getting the result I expect. So inside that same function, I added `console.log(vitalsValuesChecked);` which returns `[]`.

**EDIT** Code sample below;
**EDIT 2** Fixed code below

```
var vitalsValuesChecked = [];

$(document).delegate("#hv-byresult-btn", "click", function () {
    var vitalsTypeList = ['bp', 'ht', 'wt', 'pulse', 'resp', 'temp'];
    vitalsValuesChecked = [];
    for (var i = 0;i < vitalsTypeList.length;i++) {
        if (document.getElementById(vitalsTypeList[i]).checked == true) {
            vitalsValuesChecked.push(vitalsTypeList[i]);
            console.log(vitalsTypeList[i] + " is checked. Adding to global array");
        }
    }
    $('#vitals-measures-content').empty();
    navigate("#vitals-measures");
    for (var i = 0;i < vitalsValuesChecked.length;i++) {
        console.log("vitalsValuesChecked at index " + i + " is " + vitalsValuesChecked[i]);
     }
        readRec('clinicalObservation', null, sortVitalsByResult);

    });
function foobar() {
    console.log(vitalsValuesChecked); //return []
    for (var i=0;i < vitalsValuesChecked.length;i++) {
        var valueSelected = vitalsValuesChecked[i];
        console.log("Value of vitalsValuesChecked at index " + i + " is " + vitalsValuesChecked[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the function, or a minimal version of it that reproduces the issue?

Comment: It would help if you posted your code.

Comment: You will have to show us the ACTUAL code that causes the problem as there is nothing wrong with `.push()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `vitalsValuesChecked` twice which is a problem.  One is global and one is local to the delegate() callback.  The local definition overrides the global definition so when you thought you were setting values into the global variable, you were not - you were just changing the local variable which has a limited lifetime and thus your data was not available later in the global variable.

You should remove the

```
var vitalsValuesChecked = [];
```

inside the delegate handler so all modifications occur on the single global variable.

Comment: i changed it to `vitalsValuesChecked = []` to clear the array and removed the `var`. Thank you so much. Will accept your answer as soon as it lets me accept.

Answer (score 1):

The `var vitalsValuesChecked = [];` inside the function will create a local variable.  I don't think you want this if you're trying to push to the global variable.